# Robot framework: How to locate a input text field and how to input a value in it

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, rpa

[image: I have a search field in the web page that I would like to locate and search the extension in the page and click on the first search that comes in. Below is the page snippet and HTML code.]

My HTML is like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search for extensions" class="user-input" style="width: 370px;">
```

if I try to get the Xpath of the html path I get below Input Text path but I am also not been able to input any text and get below error

> Element with locator 'xpath://*[@id="extensions-container"]/div/div[3]/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHRke.png)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHRke.png)/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHRke.png)/form/span[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHRke.png)/input' not found.

```
Click Element    name:extensions
Input Text       xpath://*[@id="extensions-container"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/span[1]/input    cli
```

Comment: First check if there any iframes.

Comment: input[class='user-input'] would be a better xpath to use.

Comment: I have attached the picture , there is no iframe. Also I would happy to use just class but what is the full keyword for this?

Comment: You could also grab the css selector off the page off the developer tools. //input[class='user-input']

Comment: I did tried to use that but I got this error. *Element with locator 'css:input.user-input' not found*.

Comment: what website is it.

Comment: provide more HTML code.. to try different locators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Input Text    css:input[placeholder="Search for extensions"]    cli
```

Comment: Thanks , I was able to use the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this locator:

```
//input[@placeholder="Search for extensions"]
```